# Decode JSON file from API Swift Special Type Problem

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to decode some JSON data from a URL and display it in a list. My Json data include special type like in example. How can I solve it?

```
struct Post : Decodable  {
    var author : String
    var wp:featuredmedia : String // i problem in this line because of json type
}
```

A little part of the JSON:

```
[
    {
       "author":"Asil Arslan",
       "wp:featuredmedia":"https://developer.apple.com/assets/elements/icons/swiftui/swiftui-96x96_2x.png"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom `CodingKeys` to create a mapping between the model and the JSON:

```
struct Post: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case author, featuredmedia = "wp:featuredmedia"
    }

    var author: String
    var featuredmedia: String
}
```